# Can't print whole string value

Tags: android, string, kotlin, multiline

I want to use kotlin string multi-line but I can't print its whole value.

**I wanted to print its value like this:**

```
 println("In kotlin you can make multyLine string   $text")
```

But what was printed was only the first line:

> *I/System.out: In kotlin you can make multyLine string   First line*

When I looked up for the rest of the text it was inside the logcat, for example when I searched "Another line" I found it:

> *I/System.out: Another line*

---

I have checked if the value is correct by putting it inside textView **like this**

```
val textView:TextView = findViewById(R.id.text)

val text = """
            |First line
            |Another line
            |one more
            |and stop
            """.trimMargin()

textView.setText(text)//I can see the full text
```

Why wasn't my string printed as one block of text and was printed as I described above?

Comment: Has to do with Android, as in plain Kotlin your example works: https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjMxIiwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCB0ZXh0ID0gXCJcIlwiXG4gICAgICAgICAgICB8Rmlyc3QgbGluZVxuICAgICAgICAgICAgfEFub3RoZXIgbGluZVxuICAgICAgICAgICAgfG9uZSBtb3JlXG4gICAgICAgICAgICB8YW5kIHN0b3BcbiAgICAgICAgICAgIFwiXCJcIi50cmltTWFyZ2luKClcbiAgICBwcmludGxuKFwiSW4ga290bGluIHlvdSBjYW4gbWFrZSBtdWx0eUxpbmUgc3RyaW5nICAgJHRleHRcIilcbn0iLCJwbGF0Zm9ybSI6ImphdmEiLCJhcmdzIjoiIn0=

Comment: And on what IDE have you checked this, Just saw your link. thank you

Comment: I posted a link above for Kotlin Playground.

Comment: Seems weird. Like Alexey said, `println` does display multiple lines. I'm assuming this is maybe because it's listening to `System.out` and it has no way to know if the data being outputted is related to previous? Why not use [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/util/Log.html)

Comment: @Crhis, Cool, glad to know my code was fine and that it was only problem with the way I print. Post it as an answer And I will accept It.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul No problem! You may as well mark Bens answer as correct, thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `trimMargin()` turns :

```
val text = """
        |First line
        |Another line
        |one more
        |and stop
        """.trimMargin()
```

into this :

```
First line\n Another line\n one more\n and stop
```

and `println` is `System.out.println(message)` so what you will see in your Logcat is

> I/System.out: In kotlin you can make multyLine string   First line
>
> I/System.out: Another line
>
> I/System.out: one more
>
> I/System.out:
>   and stop

So you can use `Log.d(TAG, "In kotlin you can make multyLine string $text")` in order to get this result in your Logcat :

> D/tag: In kotlin you can make multyLine string First line
>
> Another line
>
> one more
>
> and stop